# SSIS - Parallel Execution of Tasks - How efficient is it?

Tags: ssis

I am building an SSIS package that will contain dozens of Sequence tasks. Each Sequence task will contain three tasks. One to truncate a destination table and remove indexes on the table, another to import data from a source table, and a third to add back indexes to the destination table.

My question is this. I currently have nine of these Sequences tasks built, and none are dependent on any of the others. When I execute the package, SSIS seems to do a pretty good job of determining which tasks in which Sequence to execute, which, by the way, appears to be quite random. As I continue adding more Sequences, should I attempt to be smarter about how SSIS should execute these Sequences, or is SSIS smart enough to do it itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there are dependencies between the processes, I just let SSIS deal with it.  If you find you have issues with processing, you can control how many processes run at once (i.e. constrain SSIS to a smaller number of concurrent processes) by setting the MaxConcurrentExecutables setting in the properties of the package.